# Angular 2: How to import/export a c# generated model

Tags: interface, module, typescript, angular, ionic2

**Q) How do I use the following interface module in the service below?**

If I've got the following model generated from c#:

```
declare module App.Core.Model {
    interface Address extends App.Core.Model.BaseEntity {
        addressLine1: string;
        addressLine2: string;
        addressLine3: string;
        area: string;
        countryCode: string;
        name: string;
        postcode: string;
        town: string;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
    // these don't work, get "model.ts error is not a module" 
    import {Client} from '../interfaces/model';
    import {AdminUser} from '../interfaces/model';
    import {Building} from '../interfaces/model';


    @Injectable()
    export class AppService {
        ...
    }
```

The files live at:

- app/interfaces/model.ts
- app/services/service.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following (dots have been replaced by underscore):

```
declare module App_Core_Model {
    export interface Address extends App.Core.Model.BaseEntity {
        addressLine1: string;
        addressLine2: string;
        addressLine3: string;
        area: string;
        countryCode: string;
        name: string;
        postcode: string;
        town: string;
    }
}
 declare module "app_core_model" {
    export = App_Core_Model;
}
```

Then the interfaces should be available when importing the "app_core_model" module, for instance:

```
import {Address} from 'app_core_model';
```

Also it appears that a module name cannot contain a dot because it breaks the import

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just cleaning up the generated file and exporting all interfaces individually as this was becoming a pain.  Cheers.